# How to obtain kibana dashboards using multiple document types under a single index?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have records in Elasticsearch as vlabs/usage - 13000 records . I was able to draw dashboards from this.

To the same index I added a new doc-type (feedback) as vlabs/feedback - 1000 records.

How can I draw a separate Kibana dashboard for feedback records.

I can see records of both doc_type in single section in Discover section.

Answer (score 0):

You can see records from different type of same index in single Discover section.

Using can use _type: doc_typeA AND _type: doc_typeB to get results but they've to be from same index.

reference link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/kibana-queries-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Document type in elasticsearch is identified by a filed named `_type`. Say that you have an index designation with multiple document types Manager, Engineer, SupportEngineer as shown below -

- designation/Manager
- designation/Engineer
- designation/SupportEngineer

Just write `_type:Manager` in kibana query box and you get all records listed in the Discovery section.